# Add static page via custom theme

Tags: magento2, template, static-content

I created a custom Theme for our shop which works pretty fine.

Just one thing is bothering me: I created some words in the footer and want to link them to custom pages which only have static content. For example (just for better understanding) let's assume I created a link in the footer called "FAQ", when you click on it you will be redirected to https://my.shop/faq -> and this is a static page using my custom (let's call it) faq.phtml template.

I only found examples for custom m2 modules (containing routes blocks and controllers) but not for a theme. Also, I don't need functionality there. I simply want to show my static template.

Is there a tutorial or description for this case? I only found how to extend/overwrite available templates, bot not how to create a new one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to call your faq.phtml file in the FAQ page frontend. You should add the below code in your CMS page configuration and save.

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="VendorName_ModuleName::YourTemplateFileLocation.phtml"}}
```

You can change the VendorName_ModuleName as Magento_Theme and add your phtml file in that folder.

Forex
phtml file page is app/design/frontend/your/theme/Magento_Theme/templates/faq.phtml

And in cms configuration,>> save

```
 {{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::faq.phtml"}}
```

Please clear Magento cache and review your changes in the frontend.

Please let me know if you are facing any issues.

Thanks,

Comment: is there a possibility to achieve this without creating the page in the cms-backend? I would like to do this completely via code

Comment: Yes, it is possible, you need to create a module, but as you have mentioned in your description you don't want to create a new module, correct? I would suggest, this is the best and simple way to add your phtml file on any cms page.

Comment: yes, I'd like to avoid creating a whole module.

Comment: Thanks, @Java_Waldi, if you need any help please email me on my email id nitish250788@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by logging in to your Magento 2 admin backend dashboard, and navigating to **Content > Elements > Pages**.

```
Follow reference URL: [Till Step 6: Generate the Page]

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-add-a-new-cms-page-magento-2.html
```

**Note:**
Once you done with creating custom faq page just link page to footer.